# Qt, qt core inclusion necessary?

Tags: qt, qtcore

I am getting confused about **qmake**. I read that i can include Qt special configuration to the `.pro` file like: `qt += core` I can also include `#include <QtCore>` in my project file.

Is it necessary to make both includes, and why i even need to add the core to the **.pro file** if can include it in my project file!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding qt+=core is telling Qt which Qt libraries are used for linking (see [Declaring Qt Libraries](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html) section), whereas using #include  pulls in the necessary headers for compilation.

As there are different Qt libraries for different things, it allows you just to use what you need. For example, if you wanted to add networking to an application, you'd add qt+=network to the config and then any necessary headers, such as QTcpSocket.